# Use ternary operator in freemarker?

Tags: java, freemarker

I just want to do something like this:

```
<a href="${ a? 'a.htm' : 'b.htm'}">
```

Comment: Try var url=(a? a.htm:b.htm)..............     <a href="${url}">

Comment: As obourgain said below, you can use `?string`, but what exactly is the value of `a`? And do you want to test if it exists, or if it's boolean `true`?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If you're using freemarker 2.3.23 or newer, you can use the [`then`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_then) built-in:

```
<a href="${a?then('a.htm','b.html')}" target="${openTarget}">
```

If you're using an older version of freemarker, you can use instead the [`string`](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_boolean.html#ref_builtin_string_for_boolean) built-in:

```
<a href="${a?string('a.htm','b.html')}" target="${openTarget}">
```

When applied to a boolean, the `string` built-in will act as a ternary operator.

---

Comment: It's not really obvious at first glance what this is doing.  I upvoted the answer, but it honestly may be more readable to just do an `<#if>` and `<#else>`

Comment: It's no very readable as this is not the intended usage of it. It's for formatting boolean values, like `Registered: ${registered?string('yes', 'no')}`. As of 2.3.23 there's `condition?then(whenTrue, whenFalse)` for this.

Comment: @ddekany Thanks for the information, I updated the answer to include the new solution.

Answer (score 8):

If you are using older Freemarker versions before 2.3.23, then you can use this macro which provides a straightforward way to do ternary operations:

```
<#macro if if then else=""><#if if>${then}<#else>${else}</#if></#macro>
```

It's easy to use, looks nice and quite readable:

```
<@if someBoolean "yes" "no"/>
```

Note that it is `@if` - and not `#if` as in the built-in directive. Here are some more examples.

```
<!-- `else` is optional -->
<@if someBoolean "someBoolean is true"/>  

<!-- expressions -->
<@if (someBoolean||otherBoolean)  "hello,"+user.name  1+2+3 />  

<!-- with parameter names -->
<@if someBoolean then="yes" else="no" />  

<!-- first in list? -->
<#list seq as x>
    <@if (x_index==0)  "first"  "not first"/> 
<#list>
```

For some reason you can't add parenthesis around nameless parameters, if they are non-boolean expressions. That could have increased readability even more.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a custom function `if` that is declared like so:

```
<#function if cond then else="">
  <#if cond>
    <#return then>
  <#else>
    <#return else>
  </#if>
</#function>
```

The function can be used in any `${...}` expression. Your code would look like so:

```
<a href="${if(a, 'a.htm', 'b.htm')}">
```

In contrast to @kapep, I think you should use a function, not a macro.
Macros produce (textual) output, while functions return a value that can for example be assigned to a variable, but also written to the output, so using a function is more flexible. Furthermore, the way to apply the function is much closer to using a ternary operator, which would also be used inside `${...}` expressions, not as a directive.

For example, if you need the conditional link target multiple times, it would make sense to assign it to a local variable:

```
<#assign targetUrl=if(a, 'a.htm', 'b.htm')/>
<a href="${targetUrl}">link 1</a>
...
<a href="${targetUrl}">link 2</a>
```

Using the function instead of the macro, @kapep's examples would look like this:

```
<!-- `else` is optional -->
${if(someBoolean, "someBoolean is true")}  

<!-- expressions -->
${if(someBoolean||otherBoolean, "hello,"+user.name, 1+2+3)} 

<!-- with parameter names: not possible with functions,
     but also not really helpful -->

<!-- first in list? -->
<#list seq as x>
    ${if(x_index==0, "first", "not first")}
<#list>
```

Answer (score 4):

As of FreeMarker 2.3.23 you can write `a?then('a.htm', 'b.htm')`. The advantage of `condition?then(whenTrue, whenFalse)` over `condition?string(whenTrue, whenFalse)` is that it works for non-string `whenTrue` and `whenFalse`, and that it only evaluates one of `whenTrue` and `whenFalse` expressions (whichever branch is chosen).

Answer (score 2):

Using Interpolation syntax:

```
"${(a?has_content)?string('a.htm','b.htm')}"
```

has_content : can be used to handle STRING (returns FALSE in case of empty string)