# If-else statement inside a parameter of a freemarker macro?

Tags: java, if-statement, freemarker

Is it possible to have an if/else statement inside a parameter of a freemarker macro?

I now have:

```
[#if myForm.id==0]
[#assign action = "add"]
[#else]
[#assign action = "change"]
[/#if]
[@printForm action  /]
```

This is quite a lot of code lines, is it possible to shorten this a bit by putting the if/else construct as a parameter, something like:

```
[@printForm [if]add[#else]change[/#if]  /]
```

Comment: Check out kapep's answer in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539686/use-ternary-operator-in-freemarker It might be helpful

Comment: Thanks @Ogen , looks promising, i'm going to give that one a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** Starting from FreeMarker 2.3.23, you should use `condition?then(whenTrue, whenFalse)` for ternary operator. That can have a non-string result and lazy-evaluates its parameters.

In FreeMarker you can approach this as a boolean formatting task: `[@printForm (myForm.id == 0)?string('add', 'change') /]`

Update:
Here's a full working example:

```
[#ftl]
${.version}

[#macro printForm s]
s: ${s}
[/#macro] 

[#assign myForm = { "id": 0 } ]

[@printForm (myForm.id == 0)?string('add', 'change') /]
```

Comment: This does seem to work in a non freemarker scope, but when you use it as a parameter to a macro it doesn't work (= in a freemarker scope): callee: Expected a method, but this evaluated to a string (wrapper: f.t.SimpleScalar) .Strange!

Comment: Works for me... I have added a full example above. If you still can't see the problem, can you quote the full error message and the relevant part of the actual FTL?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was looking for s.th. like C's ? : operator and this is exactly what can be used.